# data insert an retrival to/from database using checked list box

Tags: c#-4.0

How to insert and retrieve data to/from database using checkedlistbox in `c#`
here is my cod eon button click event :

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RosterFinal"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            var Sep = "";
            string INSERTq = "insert into T_Entity values(@Tno,@Tname,@STime,@ETime,@Skill1,@S_Day1)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INSERTq, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tno", txtTNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tname", txtTNa.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STime", dateTimePicker1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ETime", dateTimePicker2.Text);
            foreach (object i in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems )
            {
               // cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skill1", checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());                   
            }
            foreach (object m in cbDay.CheckedItems)
            {
               // cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Day1", cbDay.SelectedItem.ToString());
            }             
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
```

It is not readind the scaller parameters and givein exception that scaller parameters `skill1` must be unique

Answer (score 0):

This exception is because of setting parameters "@Skill1" and "@S_Day1" multiple times for a single insert statement.

Also, in foreach loop, you are setting the same value each time, that's of no use.

I suggest you to use following code,

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
        var Sep = "";
        string INSERTq = "insert into T_Entity values(@Tno,@Tname,@STime,@ETime,@Skill1,@S_Day1)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(INSERTq, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tno", txtTNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tname", txtTNa.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STime", dateTimePicker1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ETime", dateTimePicker2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Skill1", checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());                   
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_Day1", cbDay.SelectedItem.ToString());
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: but with this code i can only fetch 1 value. I wanna retrive multiple value

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help u..
compare this code and modify as urs..

```
ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
       string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       cn.Open();
string query = "select employee_id,Employee_name from employee_details order by employee_name";
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn); 
           SqlDataAdapter sda ;
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           sda.Fill(ds);
           DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
           foreach (DataRow datarow in dt.Rows)
           {
               checkedListBox1.Items.Add(datarow["employee_id"] + ":    " + datarow["Employee_name"]);

           }
```

Comment: this is for retrieving from database